Threshold velocity between the two models for fluid resistance/friction as a function of velocity?
My textbook says that there are main two equations that model the friction, f, of an object with speed, v, moving through a fluid: $$f = k*v$$ ("fluid resistance at low speed")
and $$f = D*v^2$$
("fluid resistance at high speed")
where k and D are proportionality constants that depend on the properties of the fluid and the size and shape of the object. So my question is simple, but I suspect it would entail a not-so-simple answer: in analyzing fluid resistance, at what threshold speed would you best transition from using the first equation to using the second?

The key concept here is related to the Reynold's number, which has the equation: $$Re=\frac{\rho v L}{\mu}$$
where ρ
is the density, v
is the fluid velocity and μ
is the dynamic viscosity.
L is the characteristic length. In the case of a wing section the characteristic length would be the chord length of the wing cross section. The Reynold's number largely determines the transition from smooth laminar flow to turbulent flow and hence, the transition from the $f = k*v$ to the $f = D * V^2$ regime. There are other factors involved such as the smoothness of the friction surface that can delay the transition.
For more detail see "Laminar flow versus turbulent flow: Engineerexcel.com"
